# Python: Scraping links into a CSV

Tags: python-3.x

I am relatively new to Python.  I am trying to scrape url's from a site and write them to a csv file.  I have been able to print the urls, however, I have been unable to write them or store them anywhere.  Any help?

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://comm.eval.org/communities/resources/libraryview?LibraryKey=1eff4fd7-afa0-42e1-b275-f65881b7489b'
r=requests.get(url)
html_url = r.text 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_url, "html.parser")
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
   bsoup_writer = csv.writer(f)
   for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        bsoup_writer.writerow([link.get('href'), link.get('class'), link, get('id')])
```

Comment: @YashTD I edited the code above to reflect your suggestions, however I am getting an error: Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module> NameError: name 'get' is not defined Do you have any thoughts? Also do I have to create the output file, or does the code create it?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
    bsoup_writer = csv.writer(f) 
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        bsoup_writer.writerow([link.get('href'), link.get('class'), link.get('id')])
```

Be sure to include the following csv import at the top of your script:

```
import csv
```

Comment: You can improve this with `csv.writer`